# jade.Boot class not found ubuntu10.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath, agents-jade

I know this is an old question, but I have spend any hours on this and now in desperation turn to ask for help.

The problem: I cant run > java jade.Boot -gui

Terminal:

```
xxxx:~/Documents/Active/Studies/MscEngProject/Work/Java$ java -cp home/xxxx/bucket/jade/lib/jade: jade.Boot -gui

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jade/Boot
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jade.Boot
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: jade.Boot.  Program will exit.
```

I'm running: java version "1.6.0_26", Ubuntu10.10

I have being working with jade since last year, but only in Eclipse. Now I must run the program in the command line. I have tried moving jade.Boot around, changed my classpath in the command and also created a CLASSPATH env variable. I even tried to extract Boot.class and run that. Im not the best programmer but do understand somethings, but this problem is above my knowledge. Help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java jade.Boot -gui` will work only if jade.Boot is in the classpath of jre. Add it to your classpath and be happy.
You can try to do this(if jade is distributed in jars): `java -cp "jar1.jar;jar2.jar" jade.Boot -gui`
Other way is to download sun jdk, extract it (for example, in /opt/jdk) and put jade libs in /opt/jdk/lib or smth like that